# Manipulate global var in a function

Tags: javascript, function

Sorry if the title don't match with my question, because I can't explain it with words but only with an example.

Here is a really simple example, my code is not the same and much longer :

```
var i=0;
first();
function first()
{
    i=1;
    second(i);
}
function second(number)
{
    number=2;
}
```

I've tried this code, it returns 1.

What I want here is to modify my global variable, say to my function second "hey, you'll always modify global variables but the one I pass you in reference is the one you have to modify"

If someone have the answer, would be great ! He could save a lot of lines :D

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is always pass by `value`

Comment: Hard to understand. `number` variable where is defined? What is the variable you are returning? `i`  or `number`? Why you are overriding `number` as a parameter in your function? I really don't understand your desired achievement.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe passing the var name as a string solves your problem...

```js
var globalVar = 0;

first();
function first () {
  globalVar = 1;
  changeGlobal('globalVar');
}
function changeGlobal(v) {
  window[v] = 2;
}

document.body.innerHTML = 'globalVar: '+globalVar;
```

Comment: I tried your code with https://jsfiddle.net but I have 1 displaying, when i try it with stackoverflow I have 2 ... :/

Comment: It might be a context problem ... if the code is running in a `frame`/`iframe` you might need to check which `window` object is holding your variable ... maybe try replacing `window` with `top`

Comment: what happens in jsfiddle is that the code is being automatically wrapped in between `//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){ your-code }//]]> ` ... this way the variable becomes local instead of global ... if you add the code in a html `script` tag it works just fine ... https://jsfiddle.net/duqayqqd/

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and your time, but I'm looking for a way to do this in a JS file :/

Answer (score 0):

Primitive values like integers are passed by value in Javascript. That means first() will always set i to 1. Second() is basically no-op.

This should achieve what you are trying:

```
var i=0;
first();
function first()
{
    i=1;
    i=second(i);
}
function second(number)
{
    number=2;
    return number;
}
```

Comment: the parameter of `second` is useless and confusing then

Comment: The code was just an example. I can't return number in this example because in the code I'm programing, I need to do a .push().

Comment: If you want to mutate a global you can just mutate global: function second() { i = 2}. Or you could wrap i in an object which is passed by reference. As a word of warning having globals that are mutated everywhere is a really bad practise.

Comment: I want to use function second(number) to modify multiple different globals one at a time, so can't use your example.
And I'm not mutating it, but adding var in array step by step